# Radians internal function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

why excel keeps telling me radians internal function is not defined

Here is the my function definition:

```
Public Function Ev(x As Double, length As Integer, beta As Double, curvature As Double) As Double
    Dim height As Double

    beta = Radians(beta)
    height = Round(length * Tan(beta), 0)
    Ev = height * (1 - (x / length)) ^ curvature

End Function
```

[image: Err Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*why excel keeps telling me radians internal function is not defined?*

Because it *doesn't* exist!

Use WorksheetFunction instead:

```
beta = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(beta)
```